# boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parser() into std::map error

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

The below code is to parse a "key=val;.." string into std::map and it fails to compile with the error:

> Error     C2146 : syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'value_type'
>   Error     C2039 : 'value_type': is not a member of 'std::pair,std::allocator,std::basic_string,std::allocator>>'  c:\git\risk-engine-core_tcp\stage\boost-1.66.0-barclays-1\include\boost\spirit\home\support\container.hpp

It does not like the last parameter, "contents" (std::map), passed as a container.

Boost version is 1.66

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

std::map<std::string,std::string> contents;
std::string::iterator first = str.begin();
std::string::iterator last  = str.end();

const bool result = qi::phrase_parse(first,last, 
*( *(qi::char_-"=")  >> qi::lit("=") >> *(qi::char_-";") >> -qi::lit(";") ),
 ascii::space, contents);
```

Looking at the boost docs and stack overflow, I do not see any issue with the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
```

Here's a working example with some improvement suggestions:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc53904d347dc069)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip> // std::quoted

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    std::string str("key = value");
    std::string::const_iterator first = str.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator last  = str.end();

    std::map<std::string, std::string> contents;
    bool const result = qi::phrase_parse(first,last, 
        *( *~qi::char_('=')  >> '=' >> *~qi::char_(';') >> -qi::lit(';') ),
         qi::ascii::space, contents); 

    if (result) {
        std::cout << "Parsed " << contents.size() << " elements\n";
        for (auto& [k,v] : contents) {
            std::cout << "\t" << std::quoted(k) << ": " << std::quoted(v) << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (first != last)
        std::cout << "Remaining input unparsed: " << std::quoted(std::string(first, last)) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed 1 elements
    "key": "value"
```

Comment: Great! Thanks Sehe, it works! I did not realize additional include was required. Also, thank you for the post-condition check, I had them, just did not include in the post.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Do note the changes to the parser expression as well. And the change of iterator type. If you're new here, please also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: What does '~' mean in the parser?

Comment: See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char.html#spirit.qi.reference.char.char.expression_semantics: _"Negate cp. The result is a negated char parser that matches any character in the ns encoding except the characters matched by cp."_

Comment: if (first != last) test does not work. It seems to parse correctly but the test is always true. How can first change if it is const iterator? It just prints the entire original string as unparsed.

Comment: Not sure how the parser itself works as it cannot increment iterator

Comment: A `const_iterator` is something else than `iterator const`. Exactly like `T const*` is NOT the same as `T* const`

Comment: And here's proof that `first != last` obviously works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3092a4c45d97d779. So if it returns the whole input always for you, then your broke the grammar (or the input) such a way that nothing (partially) matches